# Using stable_sort, when sorting vector of objects

Tags: c++, stl

I have `class Passanger` that has variables `string name; string station; string ticket;`
and then I have another class and within this class I have `vector<Passanger*> myQueue;`

now I want to use `stable_sort` to sort `myQueue`. Is there any possibility, how to say to `stable_sort`, what should be the key, according to it shall sort `myQueue`?

`std::stable_sort(myQueue.begin(),myQueue.end(), maybeSomethingElse() );` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need a comparator class. They look like this.

```
 class CompareFoo {
   public:
     bool operator() (const Foo* e1, const Foo* s2) 
     {
         return e1->name < e2->name; // strict weak ordering required
     }
 };
```

Then pass an instantiation of it as a parameter to `stable_sort`.

```
std::stable_sort(myQueue.begin(), myQueue.end(), CompareFoo());
```

Comment: A function will work the same way in this case in place of function object.

Answer (score 13):

There is an overload of [`std::stable_sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) that accepts a custom comparator as its third argument. You could provide a comparison function there, a functor, or a lambda (in C++11). Going with a lambda, for instance:

```
std::stable_sort(myQueue.begin(),myQueue.end(), [] (Passenger* p1, Passenger* p2)
{
    return p1->age() < p2->age(); // Or whatever fits your needs...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a comparator using a lambda for example (with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) if the sort is dependent on more than one attribute of `Passanger`):

```
std::stable_sort(myQueue.begin(),
                 myQueue.end(),
                 [](Passanger* p1, Passanger* p2)
                 {
                     return std::tie(p1->name(), p1->station()) <
                            std::tie(p2->name(), p2->station());
                 });
```

If c++11 is not available define the comparator elsewhere and use `boost::tie`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying your own comparison function.

Some useful references:

- [stable_sort documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/) (cfr. the code example for the example comparison function `bool compare_as_ints (double i,double j)`
  )
- [functors and their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses)